# Serverless Not creating s3 bucket or registering to function

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have a serverless function that looks like

```
functions:
ScooterExecution:
  handler: ScooterExecution.hello
  name: scooter-execution
  memorySize: 256
  timeout: 300
  events:
    - s3:
      bucket: ScooterData
      event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

The docs say that running this should create an s3 bucket and fire it whenever an object is created.

However, the template it creates makes no mention of an S3 bucket and does not create an s3 bucket named scooterdata nor attempt to register any triggers to the lambda.

Whats happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably just missed some indentation in your serverless.yml file. The section under "s3" needs an extra indentation, otherwise, the event source isn't recognized.

```
service: aws-nodejs
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: sample653536
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
```

Comment: Adding the indent hasnt fixed the problem. Does this create a bucket for you?

Comment: Two indents fixed it though!

Answer (score 1):

For framework version 3, if name does NOT respect s3 naming rules, sls deploy works, yet as you have mentioned, aws will not show it. I would consider this a silent failure, and not intuitive. If you were to do the same thing with the resource, sls would not do the cloudformation/deployment:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    S3Bucket:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
      Properties:
        BucketName: someDuplicateName
```

[S3 bucket name rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html)